# how to iterate a list of functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, try-except

I have 5 user-defined functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4` and `f5`. Right now I am using that as:

```py
try:
    f1()
except:
    pass
try:
    f2()
except:
    pass
try:
    f3()
except:
    pass
try:
    f4()
except:
    pass
try:
    f5()
except:
    pass
```

I want to know a simpler method to iterate over this list of functions while using try and except on each function call.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are variables like any other and you can iterate over a list of them.

```
for func in [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]:
    try:
        func()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Exactly. On the other hand, what the OP wants to do (i.e. `try:... except: pass`) is in general a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use a python decorator:

```py
def add_try_func(func):
    def _try(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            res = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print('add try func')
            ## return res
        except:
            pass

    return _try

@add_try_func
fun1()


@add_try_func
fun2()


@add_try_func
fun3()
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: @hengge-shine Looks like a cool solution, but without further explanation, it's rather incomprehensible. Please provide some context and output.